# Java Integer index to bit position

Tags: java, bit, bitmask

I'm trying to make a dynamic method to check a number through binary anding.
I've tried a variety of different approaches but just can't wrap my head around it.

what I need is a method that converts an integer index position and returns a boolean.

```
private boolean bitwiseAnding(int val, int indx){
    //TODO Convert indx to a bitmask here
    return (val & bitmask)==1;
}
```

for example:

```
1 = 0x01
2 = 0x02
3 = 0x04
4 = 0x08
and so on
```

Comment: is this not the same as rotate 1 n places to the left?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use [bit shifting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) operator:

```
private boolean bitwiseAnding(int val, int indx){
    int mask = 1 << (indx-1);
    return (val & mask) != 0;
}
```

Comment: This fails for `indx == 31`.

Answer (score 5):

Just use bit shifting:

```
int bitmask = 1 << (indx-1);
```

But note that you'll only get true for `==1` if `indx == 1`. You might mean:

```
(val & bitmask) != 0
```